# Software update Problem

Tags: update-manager

I am getting this message from software updater
"Check if you are using third party repositories. If so disable them, since they are a common source of problems.
Furthermore run the following command in a Terminal: apt-get install -".

please advice

Comment: So you read and comprehend the message? "Check if you are using third party repositories."

Comment: Advice? "Furthermore, run the following command in a Terminal: `apt-get install -f`

Answer (score 0):

Back up `/etc/apt/sources.list` and every file in the folder `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`, and then open them up with a text editor and remove every line where a URL is mentioned that is not from ubuntu.com.

After that write `sudo apt-get update` and try the updater again.